# Get Disjunctive Support for itemset?

Tags: c++

**Disjunctive Support :**
let an itemset **I** formed by any non-empty subset from **C** 
**Supp(I)** is the number of transactions containing at least one item of **I** for example i have :

```
vector < vector <int> > transactions = {{1, 2},
                                        {2, 3, 7},
                                        {4,6},
                                        {1,5,8}};
vector<int> I ={1,2};
```

expected result :
**Supp(I) = 3**
but my code return **Supp(I) = 1**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int getSupport(vector < vector<int> > &transactions, vector<int> item) {
        int ret = 0;
        for(auto&row:transactions){
            int i, j;
            if(row.size() < item.size()) continue;
            for(i=0, j=0; i < row.size();i++) {
                if(j==item.size()) break;
                if(row[i] == item[j]) j++;
            }
            if(j==item.size()){
                ret++;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
int main() {
     vector < vector <int> > transactions = {{1, 2},
                                           {2, 3, 7},
                                           {4,6},
                                           {1,5,8}};
     vector <int> I={1,2};
 
     int D = getSupport(transactions, I);
     printf("Disjunctive support = %d",D);
   
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that:

> Supp(I) is the number of transactions containing at least one item of
> I

But your implementation looks like you are trying to count transactions containing **all** the items of I.

Anyway if you still need implementation for the defintion you supplied, you can try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int getSupport(std::vector<std::vector<int>> const & transactions, std::vector<int> const & item) {
    int ret = 0;
    for (auto const & tran : transactions) {
        bool bFoundAtLeastOne{ false };
        for (auto const & tran_elem : tran) {
            for (auto const & item_elem : item)
            {
                if (tran_elem == item_elem)
                {
                    ret++;
                    bFoundAtLeastOne = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (bFoundAtLeastOne) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> transactions = 
        { { 1, 2 },
          { 2, 3, 7 },
          { 4,6 },
          { 1,5,8 } };
    std::vector<int> I = { 1,2 };
    int D = getSupport(transactions, I);
    printf("Disjunctive support = %d\n", D);
    return 0;
}
```

Some notes:

1. Better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
2. I changed passing all the `vector`s by `const&` for efficiency and safety.

Comment: thank you a lot I appriate that you save my day @wohlstad